# Resetting a data-grid once a column header has been clicked to sort

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am wondering how (or if possible) to reset a data grid after a column header has been clicked to sort the rows within the grid. Pretty much emulating closing the form, and reopening it.

The issue is that I am sorting by a combo box and also allowing the user to sort by clicking on column headers. Once a column header has been clicked, nothing else happens when trying to update values in the grid because a column header has been clicked.

Is there any possible way to reset or refresh the grid upon column headers being clicked but still sorting them?

Comment: i apologize for the confusion the question may have caused but to make it clear, is it possible to clear a datagrid view after a header has been clicked and remove the sorting that has been made by clicking a column header. This causes none of my functions to show changes.

Comment: Can you add a button called "Refresh" and code it to clear your datagrid and reload it with your data? i do that with OleDB using Excel as a datasource and it's surprisingly quick

Comment: What method are you using for binding data to the DataGridView?

Comment: i am using the .itemsSource method. I actually just figured it out. All i had to do was call the method to bind the datasource to the grid and first set it to nothing, then resert the itemsSource to the one desired. Thanks for the comments though guys